# Understanding the "Welsh"

Tags: meaning

What is meant by Welsh ? I searched it but still it is confusing for me in the below case. I didn't understand the exact meaning of this.

"What happened to you guys helping us out by winning the Welsh?"

Can you please explain what does it mean

Comment: If you've actually seen "*winning* the Welsh" please provide a source. "*Beating* the Welsh" would be much more common and almost always describe a sporting victory over the team representing Wales. In this case it probably refers to a league or the group stage of a competition where points scored in other matches affect the outcome. Given the timing perhaps the Six Nations rugby is the context

Answer (score 2):

In the same vein as Chris H has suggested, could refer to winning the Welsh Open or another event with the word “Welsh” in the name. But yeah, generally it refers to the language or people from Wales. Beating the Welsh could also refer to beating them in a war or battle, historically.

Comment: There is also the act of "*welshing* (or *welching*) on a deal" -- failing to follow through on a promise.  This doesn't quite fit in the OP's case, but it's hard to say for sure without context.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks Yes, this is what it was meant :) i should have mention the context to make it clear.